# How to restrict to open all jsp page except login page without authenticate a user?

Tags: jsp, spring-security

Hi I am new in Spring MVC, when I m trying to design login page using spring security module. Its authenticate correctly and forward into common page. But other hand, if I directly access URl : host /testApp/krams/main/common Its get Open without login. However I tried using “method = RequestMethod.POST” but I get error like "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported". My all Jsp page under WEB-INF coz I do not want to access directly any page without login. 
Please help me to understand this concept. Pls look into below code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLoginPage(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) boolean error, 
        ModelMap model) {
    logger.debug("Received request to show login page");
    if (error == true) {
        // Assign an error message
        model.put("error", "You have entered an invalid username or password!");
    } else {
        model.put("error", "");
    }       
    return "loginpage";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/common", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getCommonPage() {
    logger.debug("Received request to show common page");

    System.out.println("---------From  getCommonPage ---------");

    // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/commonpage.jsp
    return "commonpage";
}


<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/krams/auth/denied" >

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:form-login
            login-page="/krams/auth/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/krams/auth/login?error=true" 
            default-target-url="/krams/main/common"/>           
    <security:logout 
            invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/krams/auth/login" 
            logout-url="/krams/auth/logout"/>

</security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

For authentication see [here](http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/06/authentication-checking-using-springmvc.html)

**AuthenticationInterceptor .java**

```
  package com.sivalabs.web.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
import com.sivalabs.entities.User;

@Component
public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
 {
  String uri = request.getRequestURI();
  if(!uri.endsWith("login.do") && !uri.endsWith("logout.do"))
  {
   User userData = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("LOGGEDIN_USER");
   if(userData == null)
   {
    response.sendRedirect("login.do");
    return false;
   }  
  }
  return true;
 }
}
```

**WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 <beans>

 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.sivalabs"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="interceptors">
    <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor"/>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>
</beans>
```

Now if we try to access any other URLs without logging into the application it will automatically redirect to login page.

For authorization You can use **UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor**

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor.html)

**Usage**

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors" ref="authorizationInterceptor"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="authorizationInterceptor" 
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor">
   <property name="authorizedRoles" value="administrator,operator"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Hi Parth, As I have implemented your code, but still get 404 error.

Comment: spring-servlet.xml     
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
    <bean class=".DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
      <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor"/>
    </property>
   </bean>
    <bean class=".....BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
      <property name="interceptors" ref="authorizationInterceptor"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authorizationInterceptor"     class="...UserRoleAuthorizationInterceptor">
     <property name="authorizedRoles" value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>